# populate data from java to pdf

Tags: java, pdf

I am currently looking for a solution to populate a PDF file from the java code, Is there any APi for that, I googled it and found JustformsPDF does the trick, but it works only for some pdf and not all + its a old API without recent developments/support.

Basically I have an existing PDF (and do not want to build it) I just need to populate my java data inside that pdf.

any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use our product [PDFOne (for Java)](http://www.gnostice.com/PDFOne_Java.asp). It has a document component that can also fill form fields in existing PDF documents. Viewer and printer components are also available.

Comment: there is nothing in question or answer about free.

Answer (score 1):

These two should be able to do the job (these are the ones I know, there may be more):

[Apache PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/)

[iText](http://itextpdf.com/index.php)